# How to find X highest number in R

Tags: r

I have used the `table` function to view all the jobs in the dataset
`table(sample_data$store_name=="35",sample_data$job_title,sample_data$STATUS=="TERMINATED")`

Output :

````
, ,  = FALSE

       
        Accounting Clerk Accounts Payable Clerk Accounts Receiveable Clerk Auditor
  FALSE                0                      0                          0       0
  TRUE                45                     22                         26      17
       
        Baker Bakery Manager Benefits Admin Cashier  CEO CHief Information Officer
  FALSE  8005            264              0    6568    0                         0
  TRUE      0              0             30       0   10                        10```

, ,  = TRUE

       
        Accounting Clerk Accounts Payable Clerk Accounts Receiveable Clerk Auditor
  FALSE                0                      0                          0       0
  TRUE                 5                      3                          4       3
       
        Baker Bakery Manager Benefits Admin Cashier  CEO CHief Information Officer
  FALSE    91             21              0     248    0                         0
  TRUE      0              0              5       0    0                         0
````

I tried using the `sort` function to find the top 7 highest terminated employee in store 35 but the output was mix with `,,=FALSE` and `,,=TRUE`:

```
sort(table(sample_data$store_name=="35",sample_data$job_title,sample_data$STATUS=="TERMINATED"),decreasing=TRUE)[1:7]
```

How can I get the output of `,,=TRUE` and `TRUE` values only?

Answer (score 0):

As there are multiple columns in `table`, this returns an `array`.  It would be easier if we do the `filter` first on the dataset (by 'store_name', and 'STATUS'), then get the frequency count with `count` specifying `sort = TRUE` (returns the top frequency at the top), and `slice` the first 'n' values

```
library(dplyr)
sample_data %>%
      filter(store_name == '35', STATUS == "TERMINATED") %>%
      count(job_title, sort = TRUE)  %>%
       slice_head(n = 7)
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `subset` first and then get the `table` of only the 'job_title'

```
head(sort(table(subset(sample_data, subset = store_name == '35', 
      STATUS == "TERMINATED")$job_title), decreasing = TRUE), 7)
```

---

Inorder to subset the values in the `array`, we can use 'TRUE' in the first and the third dimension name i.e. for the row.names and also for the 3rd dimension name

```
sort(ar1["TRUE", , "TRUE"], decreasing = TRUE)
```

where 'ar1' is

```
ar1 <- table(mtcars$cyl == 6, mtcars$carb, mtcars$gear == 4)
```